# Refresh Material Design Lite Opened Menu

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm trying to find a way to refresh the material design lite menus when they are opened.  For example, I have a shopping cart and when an item is deleted with the menu opened, I want the menu to resize to the user.

I've tried using

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

But that doesn't resize the menus when they are open.  Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this helps in anyway, still check it out: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4275

Comment: @asterisk good information, but still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @SumiStraessle I have added in screenshot photos for you. The menu does not resize when I remove an item.